# PHP won't process form

Tags: php, scope

I've got this HTML form:

```
<form action="../functions/createproject.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this PHP code (createproject.php):

```
<?php
$projectname = $_POST["name"];
$projectdescription = $_POST["description"];
function createproject() {
    if (!file_exists("../projects/$projectname")) {
        mkdir("../projects/$projectname", 0777, true);
    }
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "../projects/$projectname/info.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
createproject();
?>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: projectname in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 5 Notice: Undefined variable: projectname in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 8 Warning: fopen(/home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html../projects//info.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined variable: content in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 9 Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 9 Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/wdele/domains/hypah.org/public_html/functions/createproject.php on line 10
```

I can't think of any reason why this isn't working.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a defined variable outside a function. Use the `global` keyword. Like so:

```
function createproject() {
    global $projectname;
    if (!file_exists("../projects/$projectname")) {
        mkdir("../projects/$projectname", 0777, true);
    }
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "../projects/$projectname/info.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: I do not agree with this solution, as global variables should not be used whenever we can avoid them. We shouldn't teach newbies the wrong solutions.

Comment: @LajosArpad Why should we avoid them?

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards, good question. A global variable decreases the readability of your code. Imagine a global variable used in many files. You implement a new page and include some of the files. To understand its life-cycle you need to read many files. I am not saying you should never use them, but you should avoid them if possible. I have upvoted Bart Friedrichs' answer, as it is much better than this one. Also, there is no doubt this is correct as well, but it is just not the right approach.

Answer (score 3):

You define `$projectname` in the global scope, yet use it in the function scope. There are two way to handle this:

Use `global` to make a global variable available in a function:

```
function createproject() {
    global $projectname;
    ...
```

Or, change the function to take `$projectname` as a parameter:

```
function createproject($projectname) {
    ...
```

then call it with `createproject($projectname)`.

The latter is the way it is usually done. The use of global variables is generally frowned upon as it makes code harder to understand and less modularized.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm going to accept @BurningtheCodeigniter because he has posted the code.